# mysql foreign key does not work

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, explain

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS treaties(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
treaty INT NOT NULL,
item varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY (treaty) REFERENCES treaties(id)
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

After that I inserted few lines in each of tables but values `treaties.id` and `items.treaty` were the same.
When I run

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM `items` 
JOIN `treaties` ON `items`.`treaty` = `treaties`.`id` 
WHERE 1
```

I obtained:

```
id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | treaties| ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL|   NULL  | NULL|   3  |
1  | SIMPLE      | items   | ALL  | treaty        | NULL|   NULL  | NULL|   4  | Using where; Using join buffer
```

I thought if I have foreign key between `items.treaty` and `treaties.id` this key must used and type must not be ALL.
What is wrong?

Please, help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html):

> The output from [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html) shows `ALL` in the type column when MySQL uses a table scan to resolve a query. This usually happens under the following conditions:
>
> [...]
>
> - The table is so small that it is faster to perform a table scan than to bother with a key lookup. This is common for tables with fewer than 10 rows and a short row length. Don't worry in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Really, explain query changed after added more that 10 rows. Thank you!!!!